# my php can't receive the 'post' variabe I am sending via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here is my javascript:

```
function fetchprov(proptype) {
    var reqdata = "condo="+proptype;
    hanapin=new XMLHttpRequest();
    hanapin.open('POST', 'testajax.php', true);
    hanapin.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    hanapin.send(reqdata);
    hanapin.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (hanapin.readyState == 4 && hanapin.Status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('province').innerHTML=hanapin.ResponseText
        }
    }
    window.alert(targeturl);
    window.alert(reqdata);
}
```

I know the function is receiving the data because I used the alert.

but on php:

```
<?php 
    $findwat = $_POST['condo'];
    echo $findwat;
?>
```

even when I open the php file using a separate link it won't echo the variable

Comment: make an var_dump of `$_POST`

Comment: "when I open the php file using a separate link it won't echo the variable" How are you opening the page with a http post?

Comment: like this var_dump($_POST);?

Comment: I used a separate tab in the page to show it when I click on a link

Comment: I used the var_dump($_POST). when I opened the ajaxtest.php it now echoes array (0) { }

Comment: You cant open an ajaxtest.php directly and expect to see any post data because you havent performed a POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example using jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

function fetchprov(proptype) {
    $.post("testajax.php", {condo:proptype}, function(data){
        // data is the result received from php
        alert(data);
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A mandatory header field for http post request is `Content-length`. change your code to:

```
function fetchprov(proptype) {
    var reqdata = "condo="+proptype;
    hanapin=new XMLHttpRequest();
    hanapin.open('POST', 'testajax.php', true);
    hanapin.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hanapin.setRequestHeader("Content-length", reqdata.length);
    hanapin.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    hanapin.send(reqdata);
    hanapin.onreadystatechange=function() {if (hanapin.readyState == 4 && hanapin.Status == 200) {document.getElementById('province').innerHTML=hanapin.ResponseText}   }
    window.alert(targeturl);
    window.alert(reqdata);
}
```

also a better solution is to use jquery to handle ajax